# Sharing environment variables (created by node js script) between GH Actions steps

Tags: node.js, github

I have a GH workflow that should do the following:

- run node js script that assigns a value to an environment variable (this works)
- then assign that new environment variable using $GITHUB_ENV to be used by future steps (doesn't work)

**Step: * run node js script that assigns a value to an environment variable (this works)**

```
- name: Add bespoke value
        id: step_one_point_five
        run: |
          node create-env-var.js
          set
          echo "PERCY_TOKEN=$PERCY_TOKEN" >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

My script:

```
exec(
        `set`,
        { env: { ...process.env, PERCY_TOKEN: `734573428736548273648723` } },
        (error, stdout, stderr) => {
          if (error) {
            console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
            return;
          }
          console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
          console.error(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
        }
      );
```

I can see from the 'set' output that the new environment variable has been created:
[image]

**Step * then assign that new environment variable using $GITHUB_ENV to be used by future steps (doesn't work)**

The 'set' call here shows that PERCY_TOKEN environment variable is not present. So it's as if GH uses independent terminals within the same workflow step, 1 for running the node js script and a different 1 for next commands.

Using GH debug I can confirm that PERCY_TOKEN value is blank when I try to call it in the second 'set': `##[debug]PERCY_TOKEN=''`

How can I share my environment variable created by node js script with other GH workflow steps?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution:

Apparently for security reasons, env variables, created via the nodeJs code, are not accessible after the script execution. So I decieded on a different approach using "fs".

**My nodeJS script** (hardcoding data here for example purposes):

```
const resolvePercyTokens = () => {
  fs = require("fs");
  fs.writeFile("temptokens.txt", "734573428736548273648723", function (err) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
    console.log("Temp Tokens > temptokens.txt");
  });
};
resolvePercyTokens();
```

**My GH workflow:**

Source for $GITHUB_ENV = https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-environment-variable

```
name: Share data between steps

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  data-checks:
    runs-on: ubuntu-18.04
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set the value
        id: step_one
        run: |
          node create-env-var.js
          echo "PERCY_TOKEN=$(cat temptokens.txt)" >> $GITHUB_ENV
        env:
          PUBLICATION_UNDER_TEST: ${{ github.event.inputs.envUnderTest }}

      - name: Use the value
        id: step_two
        run: |
          echo "${{ env.PERCY_TOKEN }}"
```

And success:
[image]